# Error Integration Bitbucket Pipeline and SonarCloud

Tags: bitbucket, integration, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines, sonarcloud

ALM used Bitbucket Cloud

CI system used Bitbucket Cloud

Languages of the repository: Angular (Other (for JS, TS, Go, Python, PHP, …))

```
Error observed
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution

ERROR: Not authorized. Please check the property sonar.login or SONAR_TOKEN env variable
```

Steps to reproduce

```
SONAR_TOKEN already generated and added to my ENV_VAR
```

Bitbucket.yaml

```
image: ‘node:12.22’
clone:
depth: full # SonarCloud scanner needs the full history to assign issues properly

definitions:
caches:
sonar: ~/.sonar/cache # Caching SonarCloud artifacts will speed up your build
steps:

step: &build-test-sonarcloud
name: Build, test and analyze on SonarCloud
caches:
- sonar
script:
- pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.2.1
variables:
EXTRA_ARGS: ‘-Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_TOKEN}’

step: &check-quality-gate-sonarcloud
name: Check the Quality Gate on SonarCloud
script:
- pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-quality-gate:0.1.4

pipelines:
branches
```

- Potential workaround
  No idea.

Answer (score 0):

if you already install the sonar cloud app to your workspace environment, there is no need to give the sonar url again. The integration process is handling the URL part. Also, you should add your Sonar token variable to Workspace or repo environment. After that, you should login to Sonar Cloud organization account and bind your repo to SonarCloud to be able to evaluate it by Sonar Cloud. Here is my Sonar Cloud setup;

bitbucket-pipelines.yml file,

```
image:
  name: <base image>

clone:
  # SonarCloud scanner needs the full history to assign issues properly
  depth: full

definitions:
  caches:
    # Caching SonarCloud artifacts will speed up your build
    sonar: ~/.sonar/cache

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step:
          name: "Code Quality and Security on PR"
          script:
            - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.2.1
              variables:
                SONAR_TOKEN: '$SONAR_CLOUD_TOKEN'
                SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS: -Xmx512m
                DEBUG: "true"
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: "Code Quality and Security on master"
          script:
            - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.2.1
              variables:
                SONAR_TOKEN: '$SONAR_CLOUD_TOKEN'
                SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS: -Xmx512m
                DEBUG: "true"
  tags:
    '*.*.*-beta*':
      - step:
          name: "Image Build & Push"
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
          clone:
            depth: 1
          script:
            - <build script>       
      - step:
          name: "Deploy"
          deployment: beta
          clone:
            enabled: false
          script:
            - <deploy script>
    '*.*.*-prod':
      - step:
          name: "Image Build & Push"
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
          clone:
            depth: 1
          script:
            - <build script>       
      - step:
          name: "Deploy"
          deployment: prod
          clone:
            enabled: false
          script:
            - <deploy script>
```

sonar-project.properties file,

```
sonar.organization=<sonar cloud organization name> 

sonar.projectKey=<project key>
sonar.projectName=<project name>

sonar.sources=<sonar evaluation path>
sonar.language=<repo language>
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: when I don't declare the URL said "can not reach [localhost:9000]' , then you suggest inserting pipe sonar scan instead of calling him?
Because the project has 2 steps build and deploy.
And about sonar-project.properties file it's supposed to be created by himself or I should create? because the instruction does not even mention it.

Comment: Did you import your project to SonarCloud, can you see your repo in there? because localhost:9000 error seems interesting in these situation.

Comment: Yes, i had import it but need to "connect" with token so I already declare like a env var and as I wrote before without EXTRA_ARGS: ‘-Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io  it's going to keep me saying " can not reach localhost:9000" . But even with -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_TOKEN}’  it does not even take my token.

Comment: I think I understood the problem, I look some extra examples and I guess neither sonar URL nor `$SONAR_TOKEN` variable should not be in the extra args. There is a variable  as `SONAR_TOKEN`. Can you try to delete all extra args part and give only `SONAR_TOKEN: '$SONAR_CLOUD_TOKEN'` as a variable? Also please change your lines include ` to ' in pipelines, or completely remove them. It can cause a problem maybe.

Reference : https://bitbucket.org/sonarsource/sample-nodejs-project/src/master/bitbucket-pipelines.yml

Comment: Done, ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
          script:
            - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.2.1
              variables:
                SONAR_TOKEN: '$SONAR_CLOUD_TOKEN'
                SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS: -Xmx512m
                DEBUG: "true"
This project don't have   sonar-project.properties file

Comment: Okay as we can see from the error, I think we need sonar-project.properties file. I'm not sure my setup is 100 percent best practice, but can we try my setup. I mean, create a  properties file, if it doesn't work either, create a seperate step for sonar cloud check rather than calling it from build and deploy. My setup is working so our last option can be copying my setup.

Comment: Which will be the content of the sonar project. properties file? and is a specific order to set the steps? the current sonar scan is running after the application build step.

Comment: I think there is a little bit misusage there, you are building your code without knowing the code is good enough to be builded. Sonar scan should run before building process in my opinion. I edited the post above, there is a sample properties file there, also I fully copied my pipeline structure

Comment: Currently, the build step builds successfully. But following your bitbucket-pipelines.yml file, the console still remain to localhost:9000 can not be reached. And about your sonar project. properties... it's not supposed to be auto binded? i mean my repo is bound my project

Comment: Actually, you are right, there are no notes that you are supposed to create sonar properties file, but also, it's not auto-generated. It's worth trying that creating a properties file your repo language, your sonar organization name and sonar project key, sonar project name and sonar sources path in it. maybe adding it will solve the problems.

Comment: any idea? i do not believe that create that file is going to solve my issue